# SQL Inner Join - getting max value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

2 tables related with recordKey:

### Transaction Table

```
TransId   recordKey
44          111
56          234
```

### History Table

```
HistoryId   recordKey   ProcessTime
1              111              0
2              111              200
3              111              4000
4              234              10
```

How to join this table so that when group by, will get the max process time only (4000)?

Update: The result will look like this:

TransId        ProcessTime
44               4000
55               10

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT   transId, MAX(processTime)
FROM     transaction
JOIN     history ON history.recordKey = transaction.recordKey
GROUP BY transId
```

Comment: so no need to also group by processTime?

Comment: no, you should group by the columns you aggregate upon (in this example - using the `MAX` function).

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this?

```
select transid,transaction.recordkey,max(history.processtime) 
from transaction, history 
where transaction.recordkey=history.recordkey 
group by transid,transaction.recordkey
```